# JS: Popup before leaving website but not jumping to its another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

As you know the code

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
 return 'my message';
};
```

runs the alert before user leaves a page OR reloads current page OR jumps to another page of the same website. Is there some solution only for the case when the user leaves the website (domain) by closing the tab of browser?

Comment: you could check this out: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp)

Comment: It's the same I have (including "the user navigates away from the page" but doesn't leave the website), but I need ONLY the user leaves the website (domain)

Comment: Do you mean a solution when the user whether click a link to another page (not in the same domain) or enters another URL in the url bar?

Comment: I think you want to check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063963/a-way-to-observe-url-in-urlbar-of-firefox-and-get-an-event-every-time-it-change and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060779/how-can-i-check-if-url-of-current-browser-tab-is-changed

Comment: it's not the same, you got `onbeforeunload` - _onunload occurs when the user navigates away from the page_

Comment: Oh sorry, but with `window.onunload = function(){return 'my message';};` nothing happens